# Getting a No Credentials error when trying to use Storage.put()

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm getting a `No credentials error` when I try to put a file on my Storage. I followed this guide: https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-from-react-app-using-aws-amplify-b286dbad2dd7.

```
import Storage from '@aws-amplify/storage';

export const uploadFile = async () => {
    SetS3Config('site-nocas-bucket-amplify', 'protected');

    try {
        await Storage.put('text.txt', 'Hello');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

I'm using this code to test things out.

This is my manual configuration of Amplify and Storage:

```
import Storage from '@aws-amplify/storage';

export function configureAmplify() {
    Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
            identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_identityPoolId,
            region: process.env.REACT_APP_region,
            userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_userPoolId,
            userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_userPoolWebClientId
        },
        Storage: {
            bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_bucket_name,
            region: process.env.REACT_APP_region,
            identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_identityPoolId
        }
    });
}

export function SetS3Config(bucket, level) {
    Storage.configure({
        bucket: bucket,
        level: level,
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_identityPoolId
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you setup the Cognito-user pool, and Cognito Identity pool ?

Comment: Yes, and added the Cognito User Pool to the authentication provider in the Identity Pool

Comment: Are you signing in the web app and then calling the put function or without signing in ?

Comment: Without signing in

Comment: Is it a build error ?

Comment: I think the problem is with signing in, you have to sign in in order to upload your file, or if you don't want to sign in then you can do is:

Inside your code:  Amplify.configure({Auth:{..})

add this line 
mandatorySignIn: false

Comment: Ok, I added the mandatorySignIn: false, but it still shows the error. I'm about to give up on this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231946/discussion-between-guilhermeffable-and-knowledgegainer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
I am putting it here the steps to solve this problem,

*Step 1:*

If you are trying to upload the file **without** signing in to the web app, then your manual configuration of Amplify and Storage should be like:

```
import Storage from '@aws-amplify/storage';

export function configureAmplify() {
    Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
            identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_identityPoolId,
            region: process.env.REACT_APP_region,
            userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_userPoolId,
            mandatorySignIn: false,
            userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_userPoolWebClientId
        },
        Storage: {
            bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_bucket_name,
            region: process.env.REACT_APP_region,
            identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_identityPoolId
        }
    });
}
```

This line:

```
mandatorySignIn: false
```

This prevents the mandatory user authentication into your app by which your Cognito identity is going to recognize you and provide you access to AWS resources.

If still getting the error, try this:

*Step 2:*

1. npm update
2. Delete the @aws-amplify folder in your node modules folder
3. npm install.

I hope this would work.